# Add current user name beside Logout in admin menu

Tags: 8, hooks, navigation

This is my backend style

[image]

What is the correct way/Hook to add the username beside logout word?

Comment: did you enable `Admin Toolbar Extra Tools` ? On mine I already see the user name there.

Comment: I  got an error when enabling it, Is there any way for doing this through Hooks?

Comment: you can define a custom menu link plugin, see this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/227006/47547